# Return from a funtion only when API returns a success response from backend in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-router

I need a help on regarding private routing in react-router-6.Actually, I want to return a component only when the backend API returns success response.
please see the following code snipet,

```
export default function PrivateOutlet() {
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getCurrentUser())
    .then((res) => {
        localStorage.setItem('id', res.id);
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error) );
}, [);
return   (localStorage.getItem('id') !== "undefined") ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" />
};
```

Here, the problem is , before returning success response from the getCurrentUser() API this function PrivateOutlet returns value.
can you please help on this?

Comment: By "returns a value" are you specifically referring to the `Outlet` component is rendered, allowing the protected route to be accessed? If the `id` value in localStorage is anything but `undefined` then doesn't that mean there was *at least* one successful authentication check previously? It's a little unclear what the issue is or what you are asking about. Can you clarify in more detail the issue?

Comment: "By "returns a value" are you specifically referring to the Outlet component is rendered, allowing the protected route to be accessed?"  this is the actula problem.

Comment: I don't understand... if, at any point, the user authenticated and `id` is set in localStorage, why can't they be allowed to access the routed content? Are you saying this condition isn't working for "unauthenticated" users, and they are able to access the route anyway? Should you be checking against `null` instead?

Comment: see the problem is , after successfull login , I need to call , getCurrentUser API and based on the value of Id which is returning from that API I need to allow access the routed contend.

Comment: I see, so is the localStorage irrelevant here? It seems superfluous.

Comment: Then ,how can I allow access to routed contend , is there any otherway to resolve it?Can you please help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The localStorage seems completely extraneous/superfluous if what you really want is to use the `getCurrentUser` action to get an `id`. Use a local state `id` that doesn't match the authenticated or unauthenticated `id` value. Wait until the `id` state is populated to render the `Outlet` or redirect.

Example:

```
export default function PrivateOutlet() {
  const [id, setId] = React.useState();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getCurrentUser())
      .then((res) => {
        setId(res.id); // valid id or null
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        setId(null);
      );
  }, []);

  if (id === undefined) return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc

  return (id)
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />
};
```

If wanting to continue using localStorage, then use a local "loading" state and conditionally render `null` or some loading indicator until the current user id is fetched. Also, I'm not sure if it was a typo, but you very likely meant to compare the value from localStorage against `undefined` ***and not*** the string literal `"undefined"`. This still works because the loading state update triggers a rerender and the component can read the `id` value just set in localStorage.

Example:

```
export default function PrivateOutlet() {
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = React.useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getCurrentUser())
      .then((res) => {
        localStorage.setItem('id', res.id);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        localStorage.removeItem('id');
      )
      .finally(() => setIsLoaded(true));
  }, []);

  if (!isLoaded) return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc

  return (localStorage.getItem('id') !== undefined)
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/login" replace />
};
```